# Android delete file error

Tags: android, file, delete-file

I use this code for deleting my database:

```
 File file = new File(DB_PATH , DB_NAME);
 file.delete();
```

It deletes my database, but the application then stop running.

It's ok when I just initialise `file`, se the problem is with `file.delete();`

Any ideas, if it works, why it breaks down my app every time?

Comment: when you app "stops", do you get an exception? what do the logs say?

Comment: pls, define "error" , (fx. provide Logcat logs)

Comment: Do you have any open connections to the database when you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `context.deleteDatabase(dbpath);`